What is Contrast in Medical Imaging
The term contrast gets thrown around alot but I always have a hard time understanding it. Can some please explain it to me. What is contrast in general when it refers to medical imaging?  Second how it relates in X-Rays, CTs, MRIs etc.
When searching I find about some drug that patients are given. I also encounter T1 contrast and T2 contrast in MRI and I cannot understand it. Also I hear about "contrast" on/of X ray film. Also somebody on the comment section mentions that  the term means the same thing in medicine as it does in everyday speech (which means strikingly different from its surrounding) . So all these usuage makes me confused.

Contrast is a very specific term/concept and means basically the same thing in medicine as it does in everyday speech. Did you do a search for "medical imaging purpose of contrast" or something similar? What did you find? Please show your research (a requirement on this site.) Thanks.

We require evidence of prior research in questions. That might be as simple as identifying a source (e.g.: using a link and a quote) that is describing "contrast" where you cannot identify the meaning from the context.

I think the medical meaning "a substance you inject into the patient to improve the contrast on the resulting images" is very different from its meaning in everyday speech. While the question could do with an edit, I think it's a valid question.

@rooni, can you read the first two paragraphs of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiocontrast_agent and then adjust your question to be more specific about what you want to know?

@KateGregory - As is often the case, Wikipedia isn't very helpful in this case but for a different reason. If the OP doesn't understand "contrast" in its context, or in general, or on a simple XRay (where no contrast agent is given) the link isn't likely to clear anything up. Something more basic, e.g. how xrays work, followed by this would be more helpful, I think. But feel free to disagree (and to answer).

@rooni - Contrast means what you said, but I meant even more basic. You can read because dark contrasts with light, say, black and white. As the print color approaches the background color, the ability to distinguish the letters becomes more difficult; a very light gray on white, or a very dark grey on black ismuch more difficult to read than words written with high contrast. Contrast helps. Xrays are images composed of black, white, and everything in between. Why is that? Why do bones contrast with air or blood on an xray?


somebody on the comment section mentions that the term means the same thing in medicine as it does in everyday speech (which means strikingly different from its surrounding)

Yes, this is the meaning of "contrast": something strikingly different from its surroundings.
In the context of images, we would say a black and white image has high contrast: there is a striking color difference between black and white. An image with two shades of grey would have less contrast, because there is less of a color difference between shades of grey than between black and white.
MRI works by using a magnet to polarize the spin of nuclei, and then letting things "relax" back to baseline. But we don't just use MRI to spin things for fun, we use MRI to make images that are useful for diagnosis and research. That "relaxation" occurs at different rates, which is what is used to differentiate (contrast between) different tissues. T1 and T2 refer to different types of relaxation. When someone says "T1 contrast" they mean "using an MRI to generate an image where the difference between black and white (contrast) indicates different T1 relaxation". Same thing for T2.

Also I hear about "contrast" on/of X ray film

X-ray imaging works by projecting x-rays through some tissue onto film. Some things, like bone, don't let x-rays through as easily, so this creates contrast on the film: places on the film where a lot of x-rays hit and places where fewer x-rays hit.
This works decently well with bone because bone blocks x-rays by itself, but for imaging other tissues like the digestive tract or the vasculature, one might use a radiocontrast agent. These usually contain iodine or barium, heavy atoms that block x-rays. It'll be in a solution that you drink to image the digestive tract or is injected into an artery/vein to image the vasculature. Sometimes someone might say "contrast" as shorthand for "radiocontrast agent" or equivalently "a substance that will increase contrast in an x-ray image".
So, in summary, yes, "contrast" is just describing things that stand out against a background. In medical imaging, images are created. The word "contrast" can refer to differences that are visible in those images, or the methods used to create those differences. The specific meaning depends on the context and the type of imaging.

I would say it just a bit differently (having read countless xrays and having to explain them to students): X-rays turn film black. A body placed between a film and X-ray  absorbs  X-rays to different degrees in different tissue, and is affected by the amount of tissue there is. So while blood doesn't absorb a lot of radiation, a lot of blood will absorb more than a little blood, dense bone more than porous bone, air none at all, etc. What isn't absorbed hits the film and turns it black. That's why we can see stuff like skin and blood when it's tangential to the X-ray.

This doesn't address digital imaging, but the concept is pretty much the same. Contrast absorbs a lot of radiation, so it will look brighter on the "film". It allows us to see tissue that is usually radiolucent, like blood vessles or intestinal contents. It gives us contrast to better read a "film".

@anongoodnurse Yes, of course, it's not all or none. But also, you're not really going to be able to image the coronary arteries for angioplasty without using a contrast agent, there isn't enough, well, contrast between the blood-filled vessel and the surrounding tissue. I don't think there's much meaningful difference as far as understanding "contrast" for film versus digital imaging, you're just using a different medium to identify how much light has hit your detector, the overall principle is the same.

Exactly. That's mentioned in my second comment. I was taking into account the level of understanding the OP demonstrates, not yours! :)
